# Lua techniques and libraries for LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, big-list, lua

With LuaTeX, it is possible to use many libraries and functions that can simplify various aspects of Lua programming. As Lua as language is quite new for the majority of TeX users, I think it would be good if we could share experiences in searching for useful libraries and techniques, that appeared to us while learning this language. Maybe we can collect a list of them.

Each answer should contain a description and a small example of usage.

Welcomed are examples using both LuaTeX (for typesetting) or TeXLua (for shell scripting).

**Example:**

String interpolation:

As simple templating engine one can use a technique called "string interpolation". Various attempts are described at [lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringInterpolation). A simple example is following:

```lua
#!/usr/bin/env texlua
function interp(s, tab)
  return (s:gsub('($%b{})', function(w) return tab[w:sub(3, -2)] or w end))
end
print( interp("${name} is ${value}", {name = "foo", value = "bar"}) )
```

Which prints on the terminal:

```
foo is bar
```

We can make it more simple to use:

```lua
getmetatable("").__mod = interp
print( "${name} is ${value}" % {name = "foo", value = "bar"} )
```

In this example, we set the `mod` operator for string to call our interpolation function, so one can use `"format ${val}" % {val="hello"}`.

Comment: While I like the question, it is IMO off topic and should be on [so]. Your example has nothing to do with TeX or `texlua`.

Comment: As it stands, the question is about Lua programming in general, which seems better suited to StackOverflow than TeX-sx. Could the link with TeX and typesetting be enhanced, so for example Lua libraries which have an application in TeX work, perhaps requiring a MWE of use 'in the wild'?

Comment: @PatrickGundlach you are right, I will try to reformulate the question